# Android ICS Transitions

Tags: android, animation, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

What are the default transitions in Android ICS?
I heard that there are new transitions/animations introduced!?

Is there a list of transitions used in ICS and when the transition should be applied. This would be great, especially for reasons of consistency in application development.

Answer (score 0):

i have seen that the following transitions was changed/added:

- activity in/out transition has changed
- slideLeft/slideRight when taping on a list item is now displayed as activity start/end
- in some places there is now a ViewPager used (like the effect in the market app > version 3.0)

new transitions are both the object and value animation.